# GeoServer + ImagePyramid: Request is empty where data exists

Tags: geoserver, tiles, image-pyramids

I have set up an *image pyramid* based on 5 levels of tiling. The data is served using the *ImagePyramid plugin* for *GeoServer*. When I do a *layer preview* the data is visualized just like I expect them to be. But when I zoom in a couple of levels, I get a *white* tile in return.

The *GeoServer log* tells me the following:

> 2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - Reading mosaic from file:/e:/GeoServer/data_dir/data/pyramid/2/2.shp 
>   2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - Highest res 0.6400000000000005 0.6400000000000005 
>   2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - The computed CropBoundingBox ReferencedEnvelope[534687.5 : 535156.25, 6225625.0 : 6226093.75] Doesn't intersect the coverage BoundingBox > ReferencedEnvelope[-1.0 : 0.0, -1.0 : 0.0] resulting in an empty request 
>   2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - RequestedBBox empty or null 
>   2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - Request is empty: RasterLayerRequest description:  
>       RequestedBBox=ReferencedEnvelope[534687.5 : 535156.25, 6225625.0 : 6226093.75] 
>                                    RequestedRasterArea=java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=768,height=768] 
>       RequestedGridToWorld=PARAM_MT["Affine",  
>           PARAMETER["num_row", 3],  
>           PARAMETER["num_col", 3],  
>           PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.6103515625],  
>           PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 534687.8051757812],  
>           PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -0.6103515625],  
>           PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 6226093.444824219]] 
>       ReadType=JAI_IMAGEREAD 
>   2012-05-14 08:07:07,495 DEBUG [gce.imagemosaic] - The response is empty. ==> returning a null GridCoverage

If I zoom in a couple of levels further, I get data again.

The extent of the data is [530000, 6220000, 540000, 6230000] and the projection EPSG:25832, which the GeoServer admin interface agree on.

**Then what could be the reason for GeoServer to look inside the BBOX [-1, 0, -1, 0], when my data is inside the requested map?**